# samltool returns IDP_CERT_OR_FINGERPRINT_NOT_FOUND_AND_REQUIRED

Tags: saml

I'm getting an error when I try to use the (php) online saml tool. I actually found two tools, one works and the other one doesn't when using the same values.

When I use the tool located at https://www.samltool.com/sp_metadata.php and fill it in with these values...
**entityID :** `http://localhost:8080/sso/G87R..redacted..sidl`
**Attribute consumer :** `http://localhost:8080/sso/acs`
**Logout service :** `http://localhost:8080/sso/logout`
**x.509** :
`-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIICjDCCAfWgA....
....wFOFN1X+k9gnBbdvVV1lik4wY=
-----END CERTIFICATE-----`

I'm using the localhost values because that's where I'm testing while I wait for the actual ones from another department. I generated the private key and cert values using the online tool `https://www.samltool.com/self_signed_certs.php`.
I get the error `INVALID ARRAY SETTINGS: IDP_CERT_OR_FINGERPRINT_NOT_FOUND_AND_REQUIRED`. I have also tried providing the private key and x.509 cert at the bottom of the form, but still get the same result. I don't see a place on the form for an IDP cert or a fingerprint.

The other tool I found is at `https://developers.onelogin.com/saml/online-tools/build-metadata/sp`. Using that tool and the exact same values I'm able to get the SAML metadata just fine. Can someone tell me if this form is actually broken or is this user error? What's missing that I need to provide?

TIA, Mike

Comment: I'm also getting the same error from several functions on the samltool.com site. Too bad onelogin doesn't provide a way to contact their support if you aren't a customer.

Comment: Actually I did. The tool online is a php tool. They have that tool in a repo and I found that here https://github.com/onelogin/php-saml. I reported the error in the issues. I got a notice that it was fixed a couple days ago. Were you able to make the other tool work for you? I was able to access that tool even though it's in the developer subdomain and I don't have an account.